# Github optional status check

Tags: github, circleci

Does github support optional status check in the pull request?
I'm using mono repo in my github. Thus there are many circle-ci checks with different workflow deployments. Every time when I create a new pull request I need to approve and pass all of the checks which most of them are not related to my change.

Is there any way that I can skip these checks or can be controlled by pull request author to customized the status check workflow? Or maybe at least, can I mark some of the github checks as **optional**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one possible solution or workaround (Feb. 2021):

> ### [GitHub Actions: Skip pull request and push workflows with `[skip ci]`](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/)
>
> GitHub Actions now supports skipping `push` and `pull_request` workflows by looking for some common keywords in your commit message.
>
> If any commit message in your push or the HEAD commit of your PR contains the strings `[skip ci]`, `[ci skip]`, `[no ci]`, `[skip actions]`, or `[actions skip]` workflows triggered on the push or pull_request events will be skipped.

But, as mentioned in [issue 1313](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1313#issuecomment-997006031=):

> This doesn't disable whether checks are mandatory - nor is this something that we'll change.

There is a [feature request](https://github.community/t/feature-request-conditional-required-checks/16761/21):

> This is possibly my single most wanted GitHub feature, by far.
>
> It’s almost impossible to guarantee safety in a monorepo without conditionally required checks without adopting some kind of expensive workaround – either an automated expensive workaround, or a manually expensive workaround (e.g. folks becoming human linters, type checkers, and test suite validators on PR reviews like it’s 2009 again.
>
> The end result is that we’ve ended up with a nasty habit of marking no conditional status checks as required, even though they really are required, which has led to folks prematurely merging things because we’ve gotten a bit too used to CI status being red on `main`, which isn’t ideal, to put it lightly.

See also "[Required actions workflows from branch protections should only be required if run](https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/13690)".

Also, just to clarify, this shouldn’t just be added in GitHub Actions, but rather at the GitHub level as an option for all required status checks, regardless of CI / CD provider.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of CircleCI's conditional pipeline execution to only run a workflow when a certain folder in your repository is changed.

https://circleci.com/blog/conditional-pipeline-execution/

The circle-ci/path-filtering orb will do these checks and trigger the next config file accordingly: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/path-filtering

Here's an example complex config from our repo: https://github.com/ethereum/sourcify/blob/6047a48/.circleci/config.yml